Custom Arch Shape For Composable Row
I'm working on a project and I'm trying to make the UI look really nice for the users. I have a 3 segmented meter composable that has 3 colors. Green, Yellow, and red to symbolize difficulty. At the moment it looks like this:

What I want to do is make it arch up quite like this:

I have tried what other people had said about using custom shapes, but none of them worked out. I had tried using bezier curves and setting them as clip shape and background using modifers, but they don't work. How can I modify this composable row to have this arch-like shape? Is it possible for me to bend a row like this or do I need to use actual images and Icons?
Here is the code I have for this meter object:
Card(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
    ){
        Image(
            painter = Color.Green,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(12.dp)
                .width(30.dp)
        ) // Low
        Image(
            painter = Color.Yellow,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(12.dp)
                .width(30.dp)
                .padding(horizontal = 2.dp)
        ) // Medium
        Image(
            painter = Color.Red,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(12.dp)
                .width(30.dp)
        ) // High
    }
}

